# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working without trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to using htaccess and mod_rewrite, so I have just about managed to get mine functioning to rewrite my GET page variable to examples.com/page_name/

However, this requires a / after it, I know it is explicitly added into the rewrite, but if I remove it, then I get a 500 error and I've tried adding a ? after it, which would make it optional according to resources I found online, however, it again gives me a 500 error, is there any better way of writing this too?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(?:\/)?$ /?page=$1 [L]` is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a 500 error because you have created an infinite loop.

**Explanation:**  (when trailing slash is made optional)

- `domain.com/page_name/` is rewritten to `/?page=page_name`
- `/?page=page_name` means `/index.php?page=page_name`
- **but** now your rule matches `index.php` too
- --> LOOP

To avoid it, you can use this code instead

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

This code checks if request URI is not an existing file/folder before rewritting.
Your rule could do the trick **only** if you don't make trailing slash optional.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

And **it would be a better idea** since you won't have duplicate content (2 different urls -with/without trailing slash- giving same content: **bad** for search engines).

**Conclusion**: choose one format but not both. If you choose `without trailing slash` format then you can use my first part of code (you can remove `?`). Otherwise, you can choose my second (the one looking almost the same as yours).

Note: you don't need to escape `/` with *mod_rewrite*

Answer (score 0):

The slashes are escaped, so if you want to remove the trailing one, you have to remove the anti-slash too.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

If you want to make the trailing slash optional, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)\/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't solve anything at all. You can see my answer about it.